# How can I get model from DataTemplate in UWP?

Tags: uwp

I wanna to make a listview,and here is several button in it.Each button for a website name.When click the button then access the website.

Here is XAML:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <ListView Name="WebsiteListView">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:WebsiteModel">
                    <Button Content="{x:Bind WebsiteName}" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Here is Model of the WebsiteModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace App1
{
    class WebsiteModel
    {
        public string WebsiteName { get; set; }
        public string WebsiteURL { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And finally here is code-behind:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
    using Windows.Foundation;
    using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

    namespace App1
    {
        public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
        {
            List<WebsiteModel> WebsiteModelList = new List<WebsiteModel>();
            public MainPage()
            {
                this.InitializeComponent();
                WebsiteModelList.Add(new WebsiteModel() { WebsiteName = "Google", WebsiteURL = "https://www.google.com" });
                WebsiteModelList.Add(new WebsiteModel() { WebsiteName = "StackOverFlow", WebsiteURL = "https://stackoverflow.com" });
                WebsiteListView.ItemsSource = WebsiteModelList;
            }



     private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is when click the button,I should get `WebsiteURL` and then access the URL.But I can't find a way to get the model and further to get the `WebsiteURL` from model.
Is there any way to do it?Or my way is totally wrong and there is a better way to do it?Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cast the `DataContext` of the `Button` to a `WebsiteModel` and you will be able to access any of its properties:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    WebsiteModel model = btn.DataContext as WebsiteModel;
    if (model != null)
    {
        string websiteURL = model.WebsiteURL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Tag` property of the `Button` and then access the value of that property from the code behind.

Here's the example on how to do that.

**Xaml:**

```
 <Button Content="{x:Bind WebsiteName}" Tag="{x:Bind WebsiteURL}" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
```

**Code behind:**

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var url = (sender as Button)?.Tag;
}
```